# What is this strange balance transfer that occurs during utility.batch?

Tags: contracts, aura, batch, transaction-fees, dev-node

I'm putting a single transaction into a batch utility call with zero value. The batch extrinsic is shown below. Each time I submit the batch transaction, a huge value is submitted to an unknown account. The value is approximately 500 times the gas fee of the single transaction in the batch. The receiving account is not a contract. It is always the same account that receives the balance.

What is this balance transfer for?

I'm using substrate in dev mode on branch `polkadot-v0.9.40`.

**Batch Extrinsic:**

```
{
  "isSigned": true,
  "method": {
    "args": {
      "calls": [
        {
          "args": {
            "dest": {
              "Id": "5Fmo4KdCK7jTLbaSbZ5RYXhYMZxzPCxEv7SVHwzTJ3WUbGJJ"
            },
            "value": "0",
            "gas_limit": {
              "refTime": "9,946,641,144",
              "proofSize": "709,519"
            },
            "storage_deposit_limit": "1,448,339,956,379,238",
            "data": "0x5b965eaba456d313ea79628d7a768d77e3e5089289c4ada9170a647895125b73c3c1eee80105797b3529e14b9ff72548ef16865d4d9e0f79f1e393decd2f435ff5f2cc0c133b73f06b9945447b664b3f12cf45d227a315623db8611b110b2955b2531c10340f9161523bb730b4a180f9ab0144f89ce5d0c09d0934a386fbd3b804a0a9675a0b71a30f2531b3ac73f88bd8d0a15f1e3ce7840d456947a9c3235ff5f40e720101"
          },
          "method": "call",
          "section": "contracts"
        }
      ]
    },
    "method": "batch",
    "section": "utility"
  },
  "era": {
    "MortalEra": {
      "period": "128",
      "phase": "117"
    }
  },
  "nonce": "3",
  "signature": "0x01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101",
  "signer": {
    "Id": "5DExyKNTzoweUafckatwBs4TDCyPH4C4zjXJhJpPzP8J7xqr"
  },
  "tip": "0"
}
```

The hex encoded extrinsic:

```
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
```

[image: huge unknown balance transfer]

Comment: Can you share the code of the contract you are calling?

Comment: Sure, the exact version of the contract is [here](https://github.com/prosopo/protocol/blob/bd39450fa8794ef385be198d239372a469a73b39/contracts/lib.rs). I build this extrinsics with [this function](https://github.com/prosopo/contract/blob/e817c2f61d584462226ed0ecc573bd885e26e83a/src/contract/interface.ts#L72). The contract function being batched is `dappUserCommit`

Comment: Could you please share the link to the Polkadot apps? I would like to examine this block.

Comment: Considered that when you transfer to/from a contract (e.g. `#[ink(message, payable)] `/ `self.env().transfer()`), it uses the `balances.Transfer`?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier this is a local chain so there is no online block to inspect. Here is the hex encoded call https://pastebin.com/V13ySETn. Let me know if you need any more detail.

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas I don't follow. I'm not sending any value to the contract with this call.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier [here is the full block](https://pastebin.com/xXfepmdA)(I had to create a new one as the state of the other one was discarded but its the same thing happening).

Comment: @forgetso what about `provider_approve` / `provider_disapprove`?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Neither of these functions is payable. `provider_approve` can send a balance but it is only ever called from `dapp_user_commit` in my batch tx's, which means that the [refund value is zero](https://github.com/prosopo/protocol/blob/bd39450fa8794ef385be198d239372a469a73b39/contracts/lib.rs#L1158-L1166)

Comment: `batch` doesn't emit a `transfer` event so it must be in your batched call.

Comment: This doesn't happen on the substrate contracts node. Only on the dev aura node. I am not sending any transfers.

Comment: Please provide the solution so it can be useful for others too!

Comment: I've not worked it out yet but I will post it when I find the answer.

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas I've added an answer below which identifies where the transfers are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** after feedback from @German Nikolishin below.

It seems this transfer is the cost associated with storing data in the contract. The value inside the transfer is sent to what I presume is the contract's [`deposit_account`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/98f2e3451c9143278ec53c6718940aeabcd3b68a/frame/contracts/src/storage.rs#L53), which is why it isn't a contract itself.

The value sent to the `deposit_account` is the storageDeposit

> faucetWithStore response.storageDeposit { Charge: '480.0000 Unit' }

The deposit stays in the deposit account until the contract is terminated, at which point the deposit account uses the funds to remove any storage associated with the contract and then sends the remaining funds back to the recipient.

```
            ink::env::terminate_contract::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(recipient);
```

I've created a [demo repo](https://github.com/prosopo/batching) to demonstrate the fees shown above.

Comment: > "The fee is doubled when the above call is batched but this is still small:"


You putting the same transaction into the batch twice: https://github.com/prosopo/batching/blob/fbe35448400be5338b3a12d4c9ff66b3bd83ec85/src/txs.ts#L65

Comment: Secondly, it is not related to sub-calls within a contract. I have cloned the repo and tried putting this line https://github.com/prosopo/batching/blob/fbe35448400be5338b3a12d4c9ff66b3bd83ec85/contract/lib.rs#L105 inside faucet_with_subcall() and it does produce the same TX Fee charge

Comment: Good spots. I see what you mean, so the push to the `Mapping` is where the charge is coming from. Is the fee correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.